# How to print LinkedList Node object in reverse order

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, nodes, generic-programming

In the following method `reverse()` ,I wanted to access the elements of `Node` and add them in an `ArrayList`.After that ,using loop, it will print in reverse order.

```
public void reverse(){

            Node e = head;
            ArrayList<E> s = new ArrayList<E>();
            while(e!=null){

                s.add(e.element);
                e= e.next;
            }
            for (int i = count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                System.out.print (""+s.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println("");

    }
```

But, `s.add(e.element) ;` is giving an error.
Here is Node class,

```
public class Node<E> {
    E element;
    Node<E> next;

    public Node(E element){
        this.element=element;
        next =null;
    }
}
```

and LinkedList class

```
     public class LinkedListStack<E> implements Stack<E>{
            Node<E> head;
            Node<E> tail;
            int count=-1;

            public LinkedListStack() {
               head=tail=null;
            }

     public void push(E element) {
            Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(element);
            if(count==-1){
                head=tail=newNode;
                count++;
            }
            else{
                newNode.next=head;
                head = newNode;
            }
            count++;
        }
             public void reverse(){

                Node e = head;
                ArrayList<E> s = new ArrayList<E>();
                while(e!=null){

                    s.add(e.element);
                    e= e.next;
                }
                for (int i = count-1; i > 1; i--) {
                    System.out.print (""+s.get(i));
                }
                System.out.println("");

            }
}
```

I will appreciate if someone explains the the error for adding Object

element in the ArrayList in details.

Comment: can you post the error ? Stacktrace if it's possible :)

Comment: Looks like you have a couple more problems in there as well!  You will probably figure them out once you get it printing.

Comment: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.util.ArrayList.add' is the error. - ruben rodriguez fernandez

Comment: I could fix others if It is solved.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the generic Node type as a raw type:

```
Node e = head;
```

should be

```
Node<E> e = head;
```

Comment: if I use type casting , does that make any difference than the one you have provided ?

Comment: Generic types exist precisely to allow type-safe code and avoid casts.